# Error mapping PBO cudaGraphicsResource

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, cuda

I have a problem with a CUDA buffer access : I register an OpenGL buffer to use it with CUDA, cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer() return no error (i.e. cudasucess), but when I want to map my PBO with cudaGraphicsMapResources() I get "cudaErrorMapBufferObjectFailed".

Here is my code (simplified but with the relevant parts) :

in the .h file

```
GLuint bufferID;
struct cudaGraphicsResource* PBO_CUDA_Widget;
```

in the .cpp file

```
void HDR_GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGLSetGLDevice(cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId()));

        // create pixel buffer object
    glGenBuffersARB(1, &bufferID);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferID);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, width * height * 4, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    cudaError_t error_test = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&PBO_CUDA_Widget, bufferID, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard); //no cuda error here
}

void HDR_GLWidget::uploadBuffer
{
    cudaError_t error_test = cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &PBO_CUDA_Widget, 0); //crash here

        [...]
}
```

Here is the error I get :

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd47bccd in IHM_Qt_TM_cuda.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x073ff200..
```

I'm on a x64 machine with Windows 7, CUDA 4.2 on a GTX580.

EDIT : here is the code modified

in the .h file

```
cudaGraphicsResource* PBO_CUDA_Widget;
GLuint bufferID;
```

in the .cpp file

```
void HDR_GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGLSetGLDevice(cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId()));
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, width * height * 4, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) PBO_CUDA_Widget, width * height * sizeof(uchar4)));
    cudaError_t error_reg = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer((cudaGraphicsResource **)PBO_CUDA_Widget, bufferID, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard);
}

void HDR_GLWidget::uploadBuffer()
{
    cudaError_t error_map = cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, (cudaGraphicsResource_t*)PBO_CUDA_Widget, 0); //error here
[...]
cudaError_t flag_unmap = cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, (cudaGraphicsResource_t*)PBO_CUDA_Widget, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cudaGraphisMapResources takes a pointer as second parameter. Not a pointer to a pointer. Your `PBO_CUDA_Widget` variable is already a pointer. The call should be (without taking the address, i.e. omit the '&'):

```
cudaError_t error_test = cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, PBO_CUDA_Widget, 0);
```

Remember to unbind the PBO from OpenGL before launching a CUDA kernel that accesses the resource.

*BTW: OpenGL Buffer Objects have been part of core OpenGL ever since OpenGL-1.5. Any GPU that supports CUDA also supports better than OpenGL-2 => Don't use the `ARB` suffixes.*

---

#### Update example code:

This is actual, tested code from one of my projects. Technically it spreads over several functions and the variable names are slightly different. But merging it into one single function it works exactly this way.

```
void example(void)
{
    GLuint pbo_ID;
    size_t pbo_size = ...;

    // note the type, there's no '*' and it's initialized to 0
    cudaGraphicsResource_t cgr = 0;

    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo_ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo_ID);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo_size, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);

    cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cgr, pbo_ID, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard);

    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cgr, 0);

    void *ptr;
    size_t mapped_size;
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer(
        &ptr, &mapped_size, cgr);

    cudaArray_t array;
    cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(
    &array,
    cgr,
    0, 0 );

    call_CUDA_kernel();
    
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cgr, 0);
}
```

Now what did I mean with having the `cudaGrapicsResource` being a pointer you'd malloc. Well that way:

```
cudaGraphicsResource_t *p_cuda_gr_resources =
    malloc(count * sizeof cudaGraphicsResource_t);

/* do some stuff */

free(p_cuda_gr_resources);
```

This is usefull if you have a whole bunch of resources, which number is not predetermined. In the usual case you'll not need dynamic allocation though.

Comment: I have modified the cudaGraphicsMapResources to 'cudaError_t error_map = cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, PBO_CUDA_Widget, 0);' but I had to change the definition of PBO_CUDA_Widget to 'cudaGraphicsResource_t* PBO_CUDA_Widget;'

Comment: @Hydrid: Wasn't that what you had in your code all along? According to your original question you had PBO_CUDA_Widget declared as `struct cudaGraphicsResource* PBO_CUDA_Widget;` already.

Comment: the difference is between 'struct cudaGraphicsResource*' and'cudaGraphicsResource_t*' : I don't know what means the "_t"

Comment: I also changed cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer call but now it crash on :
'cudaError_t error_reg = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer((cudaGraphicsResource **)PBO_CUDA_Widget, bufferID, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard);'

The error is 
'Unhandled exception at 0x000007fee84ce598 in IHM_Qt_TM_cuda.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000200200000.'

About the BTW part, does 'glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);'unbind the PBO from OpenGL ?

Comment: @Hydrid: An access violation means you've got some invalid pointer somewhere. The code you posted so far unfortunately doesn't show the whole picture. You really must post more code so that we can see what's really going on. Your `PBO_CUDA_Widget` variable must be either a pointer to some memory allocated with `malloc` and the size of the `cudaGraphicsResource` structure or a regular variable, which is not a pointer and you reference on demand.

Comment: my bad for the access violation, I had forgotten to do a cudamalloc call correctly.
I edited the original post to show the modifications I did.

Comment: @Hydrid: Sorry, but I think you really should start working through some CUDA tutorials. This is not how you use ta cudaGraphicsResource. I'll add some example code to my answer.

Comment: Ok I tested your code and it worked well. I also tested to implement mine in the same way (i.e. cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer & cudaGraphicsMapResources in the same function) and it worked too... It seems that my problem was that I was registering my PBO in one function and using it in another. Thx for your help.